# How can I enable a BroadcastReceiver on a button click in Android?

Tags: android, service

I have already post a question about start a broadcast on button click so for some reason i did not get the answer for my early question.The question is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278587/turn-on-and-off-broadcast-receiver-on-button-click-in-android)

I don't get the answer by implementing the answer in the link above click to start a broadcasting on button click

Comment: the question in the link is my real question please any one find me a solution

Comment: David Caunt can you find me a answer

Comment: yes it is possible ot start and stop the broadcast receiver on button click.

Comment: if so Ajay check my question in the link and find a solution

Comment: Ajay check the link in my question i have provided all code i have use please check an can you enable the boardcast on button click please bro i need a solution help

Comment: Try my code with new Android test project and check it's working and then you can modify your code with little changes

Comment: Refer this link for another approach : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16238297/trigger-broadcastreceiver-when-i-click-button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check now , I think you want like this

on Button ON Click

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.MAIN");
TestService.this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);

Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
sendBroadcast(i);
```

and this is done it on Button OFF Click

```
unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
```

EDIT ::

```
BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;    
 mReceiver  = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.i("calling me "," !!!");
            }
    };
```

and finally check the manifest file for receiver entry

Comment: did you check my question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9278587/turn-on-and-off-broadcast-receiver-on-button-click-in-android

Comment: concept in alram and mine is different

Comment: can you modify the answer in the link please what is mReceiver(is tha boarcastrecever class)if that i have implement this not working

Comment: check the edited code and i tell you that it is done in same activity with test purpose

Comment: can you please send the source code to my email please because my project is stuck at this moment help bro my email add is phenominal1aj@gmail.com

Comment: Ajay check this link please and find a solution   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305790/bundle-value-is-always-null-in-boar-cast-receiver

Comment: no man i dont but i use a trick with shared preferance i will send you my mail but lets keep in touch with this issue i will mail my solution